# Backbone pagination with static data set

Tags: backbone.js

I am using Backbone to do pagination on a static dataset. So I have a dataset with 100 records, I would like to store that data in the collection and use pagination over that dataset.

There is no database pagination available. So if I have 100 records, I would like to show 10 and then when I scroll, I would like to append another 10 to the view.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone.paginator) might help you. Look at `clientPager`. A plugin by [Addy Osmani](https://github.com/addyosmani).